# Matlab Can't End My For Loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I received help on how to create a vector using a for loop on another post of mine on stackoverflow; however, now I am having difficulty writing "end" at the end of the for loop. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
szArray=[28 63 90 100 90 63 28];
qa=[];

for i=0:length(szArray)-1
    qa = [qa i*ones(1,szArray(i+1)];
```

Everyone time I hit enter after the semi-colon of the line qa = [qa i*ones(1,szArray(i+1)], I type the word "end," and rather than the letters of this word becoming blue, the word gets indented so that the word "end" aligns with the equal sign.

What is going on? I can't figure it out and it is quite infuriating.

Comment: You're missing a `)`, it should be `qa = [qa i*ones(1,szArray(i+1))];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a bracket. Therefore, the MATLAB editor cannot be sure of what you want to do next :)

This *should* also show up with red underlines in your MATLAB editor. If you hover your mouse over the last `]`, MATLAB will show you

> Invalid syntax at ']'. Possibly, a ), } or ] is missing.

So, typing this:

```
szArray=[28 63 90 100 90 63 28];
qa=[];

for i=0:length(szArray)-1     %//   v here
    qa = [qa i*ones(1,szArray(i+1)  )  ];
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Gah, these little trivial things are besting me! Thank you for the help!